# the orderView location changed when I white the code: window.insertSubview(orderView, aboveSubview: orderView.orderBackgroundView)

Tags: ios, swift, layer

orderBackgroundView is subview of keywindow， orderView is subview of subview of controller view。 when I add  orderBackgroundView to keywindow，it  cover the orderView。

So, I write the code:

`var window: UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow! window.insertSubview(orderView, aboveSubview: orderView.orderBackgroundView)`

but  the orderView location changed, his position is higher than the original location，why?

Comment: Because the Coordinate system of  `orderView ` is changed,from its origin superview Coordinate to key window Coordinate.

Comment: I do not want to change orderView position